# write.csv in R studio

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv, na

here is my code in R for the write.csv function

I used the `na` arguments to change the value

```r
write.csv (df, file = 'df.csv') 
write.csv (df, file = 'df.csv', row.names = FALSE)
df$Area [2] <- NA
head (df)
write.csv (df, file = 'df.csv', row.names = FALSE)
write.csv (df, file = 'df.csv', row.names = FALSE, na = '20204')
```

but instead of putting the 20204 value it print only NA
could someone point out on what exactly wrong

Comment: You are overwriting to the same file, maybe use `append = TRUE`

Comment: It's unclear what you are really trying to do with your data. Please make this reproducible by including sample data, the actual output (from `write.csv`, perhaps the errant lines from the raw file) and your expected output of those lines.

Comment: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/11-supp-read-write-csv/

Comment: I try to do the same as The na Argument example

Comment: but in the example he print the value -9999 in my case the NA printed instead of the value I choose which is 20204

Comment: Unfortunately, it works as expected for me - NA becomes 20204 when I open the .csv file in Excel.  I can't see any reason why you should be getting a different result.